# create alias with the same name but not the same signature

Tags: java, h2

In order to use H2 database in our Junit tests instead of calling Oracle, I am blocked on creating aliases on H2 to emulate some Oracle compatibility :

- I first declared an alias for to_char for date to char conversion : works fine

  `create alias TO_CHAR as $$ java.lang.String toChar(java.util.Date date, String format) throws Exception{  ...  }$$;`
- Then I try to declare an alias for to_char for number to char conversion : now h2 doesn't accept it :
  `create alias TO_CHAR as $$
  java.lang.String toChar(java.lang.Number value){
  ...
  }$$;`

It is rejected with the following error message :

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function alias "TO_CHAR" already exists; SQL statement:
>   create alias TO_CHAR as $$
>
> java.lang.String toChar(java.lang.Number value){
>       return java.lang.String .valueOf(value);
>   }$$

I also tried to declare the 2 functions in 1 block, like :

> create alias TO_CHAR as $$
>
> java.lang.String toChar(int value){
>   ...
>    }
>
> java.lang.String toChar(java.util.Date date, String format) throws
>   Exception{
>      ...
>       } 
>    $$;

In this case, there are no errors, but only the firest method declared is taken in account.

So, is there any way to declare 2 aliases having the same name but not the same signature ?

Answer (score 2):

As for [`TO_CHAR`, H2 support it now](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#to_char), since [version 1.3.175 (2013-01-18)](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html).

H2 does support [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). However, there is a limitation, because declaring such functions as source code is not supported.

You would need to declare the method as follows:

```
CREATE ALIAS YOUR_METHOD FOR "acme.Function.yourMethod";
```

This limitation is documented under [User Defined Functions](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) as follows:

### Method Overloading

Multiple methods may be bound to a SQL function if the class is already compiled and included in the classpath. Each Java method must have a different number of arguments. Method overloading is not supported when declaring functions as source code.

Comment: "Multiple methods may be bound to a SQL function" so I would expect something like CREATE ALIAS YOUR_METHOD FOR "acme.Function.yourMethod","acme.Function.yourMethodOverload1";

Comment: Method overloading is supported in Java, so I don't think you would need to pass two Java methods. Maybe best ask a new question.

Comment: In java you can overload with the same amount of parameters, for instance `foo(int a, int b)` and `foo(String a, String b)`. H2 does not seem to support this and does not support `foo(Object a, Object b)` . 

H2 does however have a "Value" class that can be used for this.