# Create alias which works for strings and numbers in H2

Tags: database, h2

I want to create an alias for the IF function in H2 for MySQL compatibility as [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494009/if-function-in-h2-for-mysql-compatibility). [Vituels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35458666/1095318) explains how to do this with [CREATE ALIAS](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias):

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS `IF` AS $$
    String ifFunction(boolean condition, String exp1, String exp2){
        if(condition) {
            return exp1;
        } else {
            return exp2;
        }
    }
$$;
```

This works if you use the alias with string parameters, but does not work for numbers. If I use `Integer` in the alias definition instead of `String`, it's the other way round. Using `Object` does not work with either type.

Is there a way to write the `ifFunction` so that it works for arbitrary data types?

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21495537/1095318) states that it is possible to bind multiple methods to an alias if they have different number of arguments. This will not work for me because I need the same number of arguments, but for multiple data types.